# Как сделать ImageView круглым

Tags: java, android

Хочу сделать `ImageView` круглым, без картинки получается, но если указать атрибут `android:src`, то `ImageView` сразу становится квадратным. Как это исправить?

Разметка `ImageView`:

```
<ImageView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:background="@drawable/profile_photo"
      android:src="@drawable/no_photo"
      android:id="@+id/profile_photo" />
```

Разметка `@drawable/profile_photo`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
    <corners android:radius="150dip" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Какой бы фон вы не указали для к-л вьюхи это не изменит её прямоугольные реальные размеры. Круглый фон - это просто прозрачный прямоугольник с непрозрачным кругом. Для ваших целей лучше всего взять одну из множества библиотек. Например вот:

**CircleImageView** - https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView